# access html method that is not defined in dart2js

Tags: dart, dart-html, dart2js

I need to access the `replaceTrack` method of the `RtcRtpSender`, however, it is not defined in the dart2js file:

```
@Native("RTCRtpSender")
class RtcRtpSender extends Interceptor {
  // To suppress missing implicit constructor warnings.
  factory RtcRtpSender._() {
    throw new UnsupportedError("Not supported");
  }

  MediaStreamTrack? get track native;
}
```

The replaceTrack method is defined here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCRtpSender/replaceTrack

How can I call the `RtcRtpSender.replaceTrack()`?

I've tried the below and it threw  `_DartObject method not found`:

```
JsObject.fromBrowserObject(myRtcRtpSender).callMethod('replaceTrack',
          [null]);
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @sunbreak in gitter he reminded me of `dart:js_util`:

```
import 'package:js/js_util.dart' as js_util;

js_util.callMethod(myRtcRtpSender, 'replaceTrack',
          [null]);
```